# Why are data selectors referred to as "multiplexers"

Tags: multiplexer, terminology

I think it would be intuitive if a [multiplexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexer) was a component that "multiplied" the number of signals coming out of it, i.e. splits one complex signal into many simpler ones. However, I know that a multiplexer actually refers to a component that serves the inverse role, combining many simpler signals into a more complex one.

Why? What is the logic that went into creating the term? Might the "multi-" refer to multiplying the output signal complexity and not to changing the number of input/output signals?

Comment: https://www.physics-and-radio-electronics.com/blog/multiplexing/

Comment: `multi` refers to mutiple (more than one)

Comment: "*multiplied the number of signals coming out of it* That's called a mixer. Hah.

Comment: @jsotola I understand, but I meant to ask more specifically about what aspect of the device is responsible for it being labeled *multi-*. I might have missed it, but I didn't see any part of the linked page mentioning the name origin. One of my motivations for asking is to develop a mnemonic for the (de)multiplexer component name.

Comment: @DKNguyen Fair enough :) I wasn't even aware that such a component existed, but it looks quite interesting!

Comment: @ifconfig A slight perspective shift is all that's needed here. You can think of multiplying the number of signals that can be carried, not the number of paths required to carry them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things don't acquire names logically, instead language just evolves. Often there is a background of ordinary things. When something extra-ordinary comes along, it gets a new name, to distinguish it.

Take telegraphs and telephones, some time after they had entered use and so were becoming ordinary, at least for short distance communication, for instance within a town, or to the town's local villages. Long distance town to town, or across continents, communication was hampered by the cost of the copper wires in the link, so very few parallel links were available.

As communication traffic and demand grew, various people (Edison, Baudot thanks to rm_89) tried to make the existing long distance links that they had serve more than one channel, by dividing their carrying capacity into many parts.

The word 'multiplex' was taken straight from classical Latin as a whole word, meaning 'divided into many parts', to describe what was happening to the expensive rare resource, the long distance line.

The same word multiplex was used for various parts of speech. As an adjective, this was a multiplex system. As a verb, the ordinary one-channel-per-wire local communications were multiplexed onto the shared long distance resource. As a noun, the long distance line carried a multiplex.

If the ordinary signals were multiplexed onto the long distance carrier, then the thing that did it was obviously going to get called a multiplexer, and logically the thing at the other end got called a demultiplexer.

A multiplexer takes multiple ordinary signals and creates a multiplex. That's the perspective that's going to allow you to have a consistent description of what happening, and why 'multi-' could arguably be an appropriate part of the word.

Answer (score 4):

**multiplex (Verb)**

1. To interleave several activities.
2. (computing) To combine several signals into one.
3. (transitive) To convert (a cinema business) into a large complex, or multiplex.
4. (juggling) To make a multiplex throw.

"Multiplex" itself is also a Latin word from the 1550s meaning to "manifold, multiple, multiplicate".

In terms of a historical explanation, in 1874 Thomas Edison invented **diplexing** to transmit two individual messages over one telegraph line at the same time. Also in the 1870s, Émile Baudot invented **Time-division multiplexing** for multiple telegraph signals on one line.

Comment: This is quite interesting, thanks! But do you have any information about what specific aspect of the component's behavior led to the name? I could see data selectors being called multi or demultiplexer, depending on what aspect of their functionality you focus on. i.e. could you provide a reason for the second definition you list?

Comment: @ifconfig Combining two signals would be called "mixing" in technical literature. Multiplexing refers to "selecting" one signal from amongst many and passing it along onto a single path. Remember it is not expected of a language dictionary to be a "technically" correct document, although they strive to be. Example: "ac voltage" literally expands to "alternating current voltage" which does not make sense linguistically. But you can find AC and DC in dictionaries as words are included by frequency of usage not by virtue of technical (or even linguistic) correctness.