# Terminology: What is the Reasoning for using the Term "Multiplexor"?

Tags: multiplexer, terminology

A multiplexor is used for selecting from many possible inputs to a single output. The schematic below displays an 8-way multiplexor. It has 8 possible inputs all going to a single output and has a selector function which determines which one of the 8 inputs goes to the single output.

I am curious though if anyone knows the reason why the term multiplexor was used for naming the above concept? The word "multiplexor" denotes "to create multitude", or "a thing which multiplies". Looking at the above definition or the below schematic, it appears to me that the opposite is happening, that the device is demultiplexing. That is, it is taking a multitude of inputs and making a single output. Or put another way, the multitude is neutralized.

The use of the term multiplexor for the above concept seems the opposite of what it should be? Can anyone shed some light on this?

[image]

Comment: I've never seen it spelled with an o.

Comment: Yes, I think It's like doctor vs baker, the "or" is an alternate of "er".

Comment: Perhaps, but you wouldn't say docter or bakor. I'm pretty sure the word is specifically "multiplexer", not *"multiplexor".

Comment: @Hearth, *multiplexor* isn't unheard of, even if *multiplexer* is more common.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are data selectors referred to as "multiplexers"](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/598736/why-are-data-selectors-referred-to-as-multiplexers)

Comment: a multiplex is multiple entities contained in one container ... such as in a theatre complex, or multiple homes ... the comm line between a mux and a demux carries multiple messages in one wire, so it is a multiplex ... a multiplexer puts those messages there ... a demultiplexer retrieves those messages

Answer (score 1):

> The word "multiplexor" denotes "to create multitude", or "a thing which multiplies".

In electrical engineering, *multiplexing* means to combine several signals in such a way that they can be carried over a single transmission medium. It creates a multitude of channels on a medium, or multiplies the ability of the medium to carry signals.

The multiplexer you described allows you to implement *time division multiplexing*, in which each input signals is allowed access to a transmission medium in a regularly scheduled time slot.

Answer (score 0):

The device in picture is a multiplexer because it selects multiple inputs to single output and thus allows one media to be shared by multiple signals.

The device that would take in one signal and routes it to one of multiple outputs would be a demultiplexer.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean. There is an inherent flipableness in the situation which allows the event to be viewed in opposite ways.  My inclination is to read from left to right which means it goes from multiple to single, whereas your definition reads right to left, the single media has access to, or shares, multiple signals.  But if we look exclusively at the multiplexor itself with out consideration of added media does not it not seem to go from many to one?

Comment: @user7420124 The device called a multiplexer came after the term "multiplexed" meaning several signals sharing one physical channel.

Comment: I am also reading it from left to right like you are and that's still called a multiplexer like it reads in the picture. A demultiplexer would decode 8 original signals coming in via one single input.

Comment: @Hearth Ok so that is very neat. You're saying the single channel is actually the multichannel and the multichannel is actually the single channel (or better, a series of single channels). And so in fact the device is going from single to multi, therefore it is a multiplexer?

Comment: There are multiple signals on one wire, that's the definition of multiplexed in engineering terms.

Comment: Yes I see the logic there. I wonder though if the term "combiner" might have reduced the potential for confusion. Since multiplexor relies on speaking about multiple signals made singular which really has a strong implication of going from multiple to a single (of which the single itself has multiple interweaved in itself). Thank you though you have answered my question.

Comment: @user7420124 If you read my answer to the duplicate question, you'll see where the term multiplex comes from, and how words derived from it apply to the situation.

Comment: @Neil_UK I do not know which question you are referring to. If said question is in fact a duplicate it only makes sense it should have been closed though so I am curious if it really is a duplicate or if moderation of the forum is inconsistent.

Comment: @user7420124 Your question was closed because it was opinion based, which doesn't make much sense to me. The answer of mine I was referring to was [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/598736/why-are-data-selectors-referred-to-as-multiplexers) one, referred to in the comments under your OP, which was also closed as opinion based, so moderation looks consistent to me. Hmm, as the other question is closed, it may not be visible to someone of your rep score.

Comment: @user7420124 In which case - multiplex comes directly from the Latin, meaning 'divided into many parts'. Long distance telephone lines carried many calls, and the type of signal they carried was therefore christened a 'multiplex'. Therefore obviously the thing that created this was a multiplexer, and the thing at the far end was a demultiplexer.

Comment: @Neil_UK I also don't understand, questions on terminology are entirely fact-based as terminology and language-based inquiry is fully citable and fact-based discipline. Thank you for the link. It is interesting to see someone else noticed the issue and I see your answer is spot on. Thank you again.